# Centering text between two textblocks (texpos package)

Tags: textpos

I'm working on a cover to work as a template for my assignments (they have to follow a standard). So I have three elements that have absolute positioning: one (the institution + course) is attached to the top of the page (after margin), the other (the title) is at center and the last is at the bottom.

I'd like to print the author(s) centralized between the institution and the title. If I were to use this template just for one author it would be fine, but, for more than one, alignment has to be done manually.

```
\renewcommand{\imprimircapa}{
\begin{capa}

\centering      
{\MakeUppercase\imprimirinstituicao \\
\MakeUppercase\imprimircurso}
\vspace*{2.5cm}

{\bfseries\MakeUppercase\imprimirautor}

\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(3cm,14.5cm)

    {\bfseries\MakeUppercase\imprimirtitulo}

\end{textblock*}

\vfill

\imprimirlocal \\ \imprimirdata

\end{capa}

}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Which is fine, but just for this specific amount of authors. Is there a way this can be done with textpos?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

We can answer with much more precision, if you provide something called a »minimal working example«. Maybe you use an enhanced documentclass like KOMA-script, which offers its own commands for titlepages.

But however, what you want can be done easily with a flexible vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

{\centering{}\thispagestyle{empty}
\uppercase{Instituto Federal do espirito santo}

\uppercase{Curso tecnico}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

John Doe

John Doe

John Doe

John Doe

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

Titulo do projecto

\vspace{\stretch{2}}

Nova Venecia

2016

}

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not providing the minimal working example (first time using Tex.StackExhcange!). Your code was very helpful; later I realized that I already knew how many space there was between the last text and the relative anchor position I'd like, so I just replaced your \vspace{\stretch{2}} for \vspace{12.5cm}, which is a measure that never changes.